# How to execute animation 1 after another. JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with running function, so i would like to run animation for each div. But between 1st and 2nd div i would like to have 3 sec delay.  so far they are going in same time so i change they starting z-position. Now animation look on example like it should but.. i need JavaScript for better control. someone?
[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.jshell.net/uqww2k26/50/)

JavaScript:

```
var example = document.getElementsByClassName("example");

for (let i = 0; i < example.length; i++)
{ 
   setInterval(() => move(i), 2000);
}

function move(i){
    var str = getComputedStyle(example[i]).getPropertyValue('transform-origin');
    var res = str.split(" ");
     var pos = res[2].replace(/px/g, " ");
   var id= setInterval(frame,20);
  function frame(){
        pos++;
        example[i].style.transformOrigin = "50% 50%"+pos+"px";

}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap your `setInterval` in a `setTimeout` with a variable delay `i * 3000`

`setTimeout` will wait ( `i * 3000` milliseconds ) before executing.

the first div will appear right away `0 * 3000 = 0s` , the second after `3s ( 1 * 3000 = 3s` and the third after `6s ( 2 * 3000 = 6s )`

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var id = setInterval(frame,  i ); 
}, i * 3000)
```

i don't know what you meant by changing the z-position but here's a fiddle that you can play around with : https://fiddle.jshell.net/uqww2k26/85/

```js
var example = document.getElementsByClassName("example");

for (let i = 0; i < example.length; i++)
{ 
  move(i);
}

function move(i){
 var str = getComputedStyle(example[i]).getPropertyValue('transform-origin');
 var res = str.split(" ");
 var pos = res[2].replace(/px/g, " ");
  
  setTimeout(function(){
   setInterval(frame,  i ); 
  }, i * 3000)
  
  function frame(){
   pos++;
   example[i].style.transformOrigin = "50% 50% "+pos+"px";
 }
}
```

```css
body {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.example {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  
}
#background{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
}
.example:nth-child(2n+0) {  
  
  margin-left: 30px;
}
.example:nth-child(3){
transform: perspective(50px);
transform-origin: 50% 50% -300px;
top:40%;
}
.example:nth-child(2){
transform: perspective(50px);
transform-origin: 50% 50% -250px;
top:20%;
}
.example:nth-child(1){
transform: perspective(50px);
transform-origin: 50% 50% -200px;
}


.background {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-style: solid;

}

.num {
  display: inline-block;
  color: orange;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;

}
```

```html
<div id="background">
  <div class="example">
    <p class="num">
      Example
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="example">
    <p class="num">
      Example 2
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="example">
    <p class="num">
      Example 3
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```